# Get children of state object

Tags: reactjs

In my react-app, I fetch data from the server and store it in the state in `data` like this:

```
  React.useEffect(() => {
    const fetchWidgets = async () => {
      const response = await fetch("http://localhost:1202/data");
      const responseData = await response.json();
      setData(responseData);
    };
    fetchWidgets();
  }, []);
```

The resulting object looks loke this:

```
data = {
    "Widget1": "notes",
    "Widget2": "weather",
    "Widget3": "clock",
    "Widget4": "news"
  }
```

If I want to get the value of `Widget1`, how can I do that?
If I try `data.Widget1` I get this error message: `Property 'Widget1' does not exist on type 'object'.`

Thanks for your help!

Comment: How have you defined useState type

Comment: `data["Widget1"]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to type of value useState returns

```
interface DataType {
    [key: string]: string
}

const [data, setState] = useState<DataType>({})
```